Ignore extra tabs in last column
I am reading a .tsv file into duckdb. In a couple rows, the last column has extra tabs in it, so duckdb sees extra columns.
Is there a way I can ignore any tabs in the last column, or do I have to use something like regex to remove the extra tabs?
So far, I've just deleted the extra tabs by hand. Looking for a better solution

Can you provide an actual runnable example? i.e. code that generates a sample tsv file along with the duckdb code you're using to read it in, and the intended final result.
